# passing custom cell from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

if I have one view controller (the main one) which includes a custom cells and when the user clicks on one of the custom cells, another view controller will be open with the detail of the event that was listed in the custom cell, there is a UIBUtton on the second VC (details VC) once this button is pressed a copy of the custom cell that has led to the current details ViewController will be listed in another ViewController (will be saved there) my question is how to do that ?? i have searched a lot but nothing is really helpful, i would appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't pass a cell from a view controller to another. You pass data. Then each view controller can display whatever view(s) it needs based on the data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do (and I'm only half sure that I do) then you probably want to do something like this:

Display table view 1 -> Tap custom cell -> Seague to new view -> Display the same cell

If this is the case then personally I'd setup NSNotifications to send the appropriate data through to the new UIViewController where you can simply recreate a table view with only one cell and input the appropriate data into it. So:

Display table view 1 -> Tap custom cell -> Instantiate new view -> Post NSNotification containing cell data -> Seague to new view -> Load data carried in NSNotification into cell which is loaded in table view -> reload table view

Or something like that. There are cleaner ways to do it, for instance if you're only going to ever want to display one cell then I would personally recreate it within that view so you don't have to load a complete tableview every time that view opens for only one record.

Comment: I think u quiet misunderstood my question. basically two bottom tab bars the first one contain UITable with custom cells once the cell is clicked ---> segue to a new view (inside this view there is a UIbutton) once this button is clicked --> a copy of the custom cell in the first VC for the first tab bar will be inserted in the UITable view controller for the second bottom tab bar which means when the user click on the second bottom tab bar he/she will be able to view that custom cell.